# Files not found error when tried to upload files using AutoIT and Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, autoit

When I am trying to run the AutoIT.exe script or my Selenium script, it is throwing `'File Not found error'`. Please suggest!

Selenium code snippet: ===================================

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.get("http://demo.automationtesting.in/Register.html"); 
driver.manage().window().maximize(); Thread.sleep(2000); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='imagesrc' and @type='file']")).click(); 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Selenium practise\\SeleniumAssignment\\AutoIT\\MultipleFileUpload.exe"+" "+"C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\0234_005.pdf"); Thread.sleep(2000); 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='imagesrc' and @type='file']")).click(); 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\Selenium practise\\SeleniumAssignment\\AutoIT\\MultipleFileUpload.exe"+" "+"C:\\Users\\IBM_ADMIN\\Desktop\\BRP_SujataChakraborty.pdf"); driver.quit(); }
```

AutoIt Code Snippet: ============================

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1") 
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[0]) 
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[1]) 
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1",$CmdLine[2]) 
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You're missing the detailed error description. `'File Not found error'` obvious tells you any script can't find a file. You have to check paths and make sure the file exists. Since we don't know which script and which line throws the error, we can't help. -- **Edit:** If you're telling us what you're trying to do, people probably got better solutions then just doing remote-clicks ..

Answer (score 0):

Is brower file dialog active window? If not auto it script will enter value in window whichever is active. Do make sure file dialog active?. Do interact with brower once it is started. And one more thing if you input type is file then you can use send keys instead of auto it to enter value.